# How can I use 2 dropdown filters with bootstrap 4 in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a website that has a 'projects' page. On this page, they show all their finished projects to show to there clients. Now, they want 2 filters to it. 1 for the 'type of service' and 1 for the 'type of structure'. 
I want to have it inside a dropdown list but it seems only to work with 'a element' and not with 'data-list' which I'm using right now. But the problem with the 'data-list' attribute is that it only works for 1 filter.

Can't figure it out how I can do this... But there must be a way, right?

Thanks in advance! 
Grts

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: We need more clarity about your code... are you using a plugin that we should consider as required or you are looking for a jQuery solution to multiple filtering using data attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This method matches classnames with the values found in data-list attribute in both select boxes. Logical operators used here would help you choose between exclusive or inclusive condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('select').on('change',function(){
var struct=$('.structure').find(':selected').attr('data-list');
var serv=$('.service').find(':selected').attr('data-list');
$('.project').each(function() {
var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
//console.log(classList);
if(struct==='all' && serv==='all') {
$('.project').show();
} else if(struct==='all' || serv==='all') {
$(this).toggle((classList.includes(struct) || classList.includes(serv)));
} else{
$(this).toggle((classList.includes(struct) && classList.includes(serv)));
}
});

});
});
```

```css
img{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="project" class="structure">
    <option data-list="all">--Filter by Structure--</option>
    <option data-list="hotel">Hotels</option>
    <option data-list="house">Houses</option>
    <option data-list="office">Office</option>
    <option data-list="theater">Theaters</option>
</select>
<select name="service" class="service">
    <option data-list="all">--Filter by Service--</option>
    <option data-list="Deco">Deco</option>
    <option data-list="Design">Design</option>
    <option data-list="Construction">Construction</option>
    <option data-list="Lighting">Lighting</option>
</select>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3 project hotel Construction">
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/H%C3%B4tel_du_Lac_Tunis.jpg">

</div>

<div class="col-md-3 project house Construction">
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Teremok_%28Talashkino%3B_2013-11-10%29_02.JPG">

</div>
<div class="col-md-3 project theater Lighting">
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Palais_Garnier._December_5%2C_2010.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 project office Lighting">
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/London_MMB_%C2%BB093_15_Westferry_Circus.jpg/640px-London_MMB_%C2%BB093_15_Westferry_Circus.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 project house Deco">
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/The_16_house_on_the_Beautiful_Street_from_Bucharest_%28Romania%29_1.jpg">

</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 project hotel Design">
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Toru%C5%84%2C_Hotel_Polonia.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for a good plugin, I suggest [MixItUp](https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/) or [iSotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Comment: That was all I was looking for, much appreciate!

Comment: You can set it as an accepted answer then :) You are welcome !